# Any method similar to sprintf in Java?

Tags: java, formatter

Any similar method to sprintf in Java?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sprintf equivalent in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045/sprintf-equivalent-in-java)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Complicated way (using Formatter)

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// Send all output to the Appendable object sb
Formatter formatter = new Formatter(sb, Locale.US);

// Explicit argument indices may be used to re-order output.
formatter.format("%4$2s %3$2s %2$2s %1$2s", "a", "b", "c", "d")
```

Or simpler way:

```
String.format
```

Comment: @user496949 - per SDK you can use same argument two or more times in any order, `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion` - so index$ - is optional marker that allows you specify format string in other orders than source arguments.

Answer (score 14):

In a way the String.format is like having a Java sprintf method available here

```
String status = String.format("The rename status is (%d)", RENAME_SUCCEEDED);
```

You can see the [example](http://www.devdaily.com/blog/post/software-dev/cheat-sheet-reference-printf-format-specifier-syntax) here as well

Answer (score 10):

You're looking for

[`String.format`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29).

Answer (score 2):

Yes: [Formatted Printing for Java (sprintf)](http://web.archive.org/web/20120626122958/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/sprintf/)

Comment: Sadly this link redirects to generic page http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index.html

Comment: @RussellSilva, changed the link to point to an archived version of the  article.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Formatter classs and Javadoc:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the irrational prejudice against unsigned numeric data extends to this as well.  The %u format element is conspicuously absent from the supported set.