# Replacing multiple strings with one in java code

Tags: java, string, text, merge, concatenation

I need to replace:

```
myVariable = "sample string is long " +
  "so I put rest of it in 2nd line." +
  " And sometimes in 3rd and so on";
```

with:

```
myVariable = "sample string is long so I put rest of it in 2nd line. And sometimes in 3rd and so on";
```

Additional issue: how to merge entities like above I they have other variables in concatenation chain?

```
myVar = "The number of the beast is " + numberOfTheBeast + " !!! So I said";
```

What I'd like to do is to change it into single string with params inside.

Comment: Dont understand your question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045/sprintf-equivalent-in-java

Comment: Please don't post multiple issues in one question. Your first issue is an IDE-specific question - which IDE are you using? Also... why are you doing this?

Comment: You mean in code or in runtime? I don't really understand the question itself.

Comment: Let me try to explain why I need to do this.
I have this code to maintain and I need to get rid of those string concatenations (also to i18n those strings).

Comment: Those are completely different tasks. The first one is easy to do with a regular expression, the second will probably require a rather huge amount of work, because you need to do type-checking, etc. Writing an IDE extension is probably the easiest way to go (since it has type-checking built-in).

Comment: Dukeling - thanks, I thnik I'll play with IntelliJ

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a regular expression guru, but these three regex replaces should do the trick.  Most IDEs have a regex replace function.

```
Replace:     With:
\s*\+\s*\n    +   (space, plus, space)
"\s*\+\s*"   nothing
\s*\+\s*      +   (space, plus, space)
```

You might have to use \s*+\s*\r\n for the first regex, if you are on Windows.