# java how to replace ? in string with values

Tags: java

In theory simple thing but I can't find the answer.

Let's assume we have the String:

```
"Today at ? cars yellow: ? cars red: ? cars black ?"
```

And now I want to create to execute some function `X` in the following way:

```
X("Today at ? cars yellow: ? cars red: ? cars black", value1, value 2, value 3, value 4)
```

to get as result the string:

```
"Today at 12:00 cars yellow: 123 cars red: 11 cars black 24"
```

Is there any `X` function ready to be used from the shelf? If not how to write my own?

Comment: If you switch to using `%d` (and/or `%s`) instead of `?` then you could use [String.format](http://tinyurl.com/java-string-format2)

Comment: Maybe [`String.format()`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/47049) would help ?

Comment: Do you have to use `?` or can it be something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could easily make one:

```
static String X(String sentence, String... args) {
   for (String arg : args) {
        sentence = sentence.replaceFirst("\\?", arg);
    }
    return sentence;
}
```

If you are able to modify what the strings look like and use `%s` instead of `?` you could use [String.format()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) instead.

Comment: Since when `String.format` uses `{0}`? I thought it was `%[argument_index$][flags][width][.precision]conversion`. Maybe you mean `MessageFormat.format` like in [Fouad's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645442/1393766).

Comment: That would be the perfect solution if I could call it easily ex. for X(string, long, long, string). Otherwise I have to convert manually args to String first. But still big thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can eventually use MessageFormat even if the placeholder is not ? but {x} with x the position of the variable in the input list: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html

Answer (score 2):

Check out the String.format() docs: [String.format() javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29)

Answer (score 1):

```
static String x(final String format, final Object... values) {

    String f = format.replace("%", "%%");

    f = f.replace("?", "%s");

    return String.format(f, values);
}
```

Comment: A better version, handling % occurrences in the input.

Answer (score 1):

This should work fine, look into the String.format() method. Replace each instance of "?" with "%s" and then call String.format and pass all your arguments.

```
while(myString.contains("?")){
  myString = myString.subString(0,myString.indexOf("?")) + "%s" + myString.subString(myString.indexOf("?" + 1));
}
String final = String.format(myString, val1, val2, val3);
```

Comment: what if my string already contains % used for other purposes?

Comment: That's a good point. You'd have to sanitize the string first, you could convert % into something else and then back to % after the format. But then you need a special symbol that won't be used.
String s = "test?%"
s = s.replace("%", "@");
s = s.replace("?","%s");
s = String.format(s, arg, arg, arg);
s = s.replace("@","%");

Answer (score 1):

The following solution, inspired by Kevin DiTraglia, I would treat as perfect (you can have different objects and primitive types as arguments, not only Strings).

```
/** replaces ? with arguments */
public static String format (String text, Object... args) {
       for (Object arg : args) {
            text = text.replaceFirst(SPECIAL_CHAR, arg.toString());
        }
    return text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there exists a method for this in java. But one of the implementations can be this (although its tooooo problem specific)

```
public static String X(String s,String s1,String s2,String s3,String s4){
    String[] array = s.split("\\?");
    s=array[0]+s1+array[1]+s2+array[2]+s3+array[3]+s4;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: or maybe see [Kevin DiTraglia's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19645502/1521453), its better in case you have an array of arguments.