# Formating a string in Java when I'm not printing it

Tags: java, string-formatting

How can I format a string in Java when I'm not printing it?

Eg. in Python I can do :

```
s = "%f" % f
```

All the Java examples I'm seeing online are using printf or some streams. How can I just create a formatted string internally?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045/sprintf-equivalent-in-java

Comment: `String.format` is what you're looking for,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...))

```
String value = String.format("%.2f", doubleValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the String Formatter class:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

```
public class Format {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = String.format("%f ", myfloat);
}
```

}